# Prove that if (a,b) are positive integers with gcd(a,bc) = gcd(a,b)gcd(a,c) , then gcd(a,b)=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let a and b be positive integers with $gcd(a,bc)$ =  $gcd(a,b)gcd(a,c) $ ∀ positive integer c $=>$ $gcd(a,b)=1$

Let $gcd(a,bc)=d$ , $gcd(a,b)=d_{1}$ , $gcd(a,c)=d_{2}$

I try to prove $d_{2}$|$d$ and $d$|$d_{2}$

It is easy to show $d_{2}$|$d$
,but I don't know how to show $d$|$d_{2}$,
or show
$d$ is common divisor of  (a,c)

Since if $d$ is a common divisor of  (a,c), I can know $d$ ≤ $d_{2}$

and  $d_{2}$|$d$ => $d_{2}$ ≤ $d$,
then I have $d_{2}$ = $d$

Hence, I can conclude $d_{1}$ = 1

Comment: *Hint*: choose $c$ appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd}(a,b).$$
$$2)\text{ }\text{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{gcd}(a,b^n) = \text{gcd}(a,b)\text{gcd}(a,b^{n-1}).$$
$$3) \text{ }\text{gcd}(a,b^n) = \text{gcd}(a,b)^n.$$

$$4)\text{ } \text{gcd}(a,b^n) \leq a.$$

$$5) \text{ }\text{gcd}(a,b)\geq 2 \Rightarrow \text{gcd}(a,b^n) = \text{gcd}(a,b)^n \geq 2^n.$$

$$6)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } 4), 5) \Rightarrow \text{gcd}(a,b) \leq 1. $$

$$7)\text{ }\text{ }a,b \geq 1 \Rightarrow \text{gcd}(a,b) = 1.$$

Comment: It's easier than that $-$ just put $c=a$, and the result is immediate.

Comment: @TonyK $a,b$ are fixed while $c$ is not.

Comment: @DerekLuna, the equation is true for all positive integers $c$. So in particular it is true for the choice $c=a$.

Comment: @TonyK I see what you are saying now, although one one questions whether it was really meant to be written that way.

Comment: Ofcourse...why did I miss that.